# Dynamic linq enums filtering error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dynamic-linq

I trying to use dynamic linq for runtime datagrid filtering with [DataGridFiltering project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering).but i have a problem with enums.

for example, i have a class which contain an enum property like this :

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(int id,string name,StudentType type)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public StudentType Type { get; set; }
}
```

and StudentType enum is :

```
public enum StudentType : byte
{
    Normal=0,
    Good
};
```

i create a controller class for work with list of students.

in my controller i have a method to find students by type.

this is FindByType Method:

```
    public IList<Student> FindByType(string type)
    {
        return _students.AsQueryable().Where("Type.ToString().StartWith(@0)",type).ToList();
    }
```

when i call FindByType Method i get this error in ParseMemberAccess method of dynamic linq:

> Methods on type 'Enum' are not accessible

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the dynamic linq library you are using does not support any Enum methods, such as Enum.Equals(otherVal), or Enum.ToString(). One way to get around this, if you have to use dynamic-linq is :

```
public IList<Student> FindByType(StudentType type)
{
    return _students.AsQueryable().Where("Type  = (@0)", type).ToList();
}
```

However, if you are able to use standard linq, and you really want to pass in a string for some reason, something like this is much cleaner:

```
public IList<Student> FindByType(string type)
{
    return _students.Where(s => s.Type.ToString().StartsWith(type)).ToList();
}
```

**Edit :**
If you need the ability to search using StartsWith and you are not allowed to use the standard linq query above, here is something that will give the same result with alot more code

```
public IList<Student> FindByType(string type)
{
    //Replace e.StartsWith with whatever method you wish to filter by
    var studentTypeNames =typeof(StudentType).GetEnumNames().Where(e => e.StartsWith(type)).ToList();
    var students = new List<Student>();
    foreach (var studentTypeName in studentTypeNames)
    {
        StudentType studentType;
        Enum.TryParse(studentTypeName, true, out studentType);
        students.AddRange(_students.AsQueryable().Where("Type  = (@0)", studentType).ToList());
    }
    return students;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i using latest version of dynamic linq. because i using datagridfilter i can't write Type instate of Type.ToString(). user don't know it's an enum user see Type field az string so need to filter it by Start With, End With or Contains Conditions.

Comment: I have added in code that will allow you to specify a string and you will get back the list you wish for, with StartsWith filtering. However, you should be able to get what you want with the middle piece of code, since that one also accepts a string method and uses StartsWith filtering. Is there any reason you cannot use standard Linq?

Answer (score -1):

In Dynamic Linq you cann't call methods from class that not in predefined classes array, for workaround you may add property in Student class like this:

```
public string StudentTypeString {get {return Type.ToString(); } }
```

and use next query

```
public IList<Student> FindByType(string type)
{
    return _students.AsQueryable().Where("StudentTypeString.StartWith(@0)",type).ToList();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by predefined in classes array?

Comment: @liang i mean `static readonly Type[] predefinedTypes` in DinamicLinq source, if this field not contains your type then will be raise ParseError with reason `MethodsAreInaccessible`

Comment: @GrundyThat must've been the reason of parsing error when I tried to use extension method on the property of Student class directly. From what I experimented, using extension methods in the property/function even defined in Student class would also fail for some parsing error.

Comment: can you create your own question with sample code? i don't quite understand what you mean :-)